# Fitting data with two variables

Tags: fitting

I have a proble with Mathematica:
I've imported data in the form: {{2.0,2.2},{4.0,4.2},{6.0,6.2},,...,{x,y}} from a file and I want to fit them (with a line o other function) but I don't know how to use Fit or FindFit function with two variables (I'd like the first component on the x axis and the second on the y one).
Thank you for ypur help!

Comment: The first example in the `Fit` documentation is really good and matches your data perfectly.

Comment: its not clear from the description how your data is structured. Typically 2d data would be `{{x1,y1,f[x1,y1]},{x2,y2,f[x2,y2]}, ...}`  (dimension 3xn).  You show only a 2x3 array.

Comment: I have n{x,y} couples